# Print out plots for each group in list column

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

A list column with some plots:

```
mydiamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  nest %>% 
  mutate(plots = map(data, ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = x, y = price)) + geom_point()))

mydiamonds
# A tibble: 35 × 4
# Groups:   cut, color [35]
   cut       color data                 plots 
   <ord>     <ord> <list>               <list>
 1 Ideal     E     <tibble [3,903 × 8]> <gg>  
 2 Premium   E     <tibble [2,337 × 8]> <gg>  
 3 Good      E     <tibble [933 × 8]>   <gg>  
 4 Premium   I     <tibble [1,428 × 8]> <gg>  
 5 Good      J     <tibble [307 × 8]>   <gg>  
 6 Very Good J     <tibble [678 × 8]>   <gg>  
 7 Very Good I     <tibble [1,204 × 8]> <gg>  
 8 Very Good H     <tibble [1,824 × 8]> <gg>  
 9 Fair      E     <tibble [224 × 8]>   <gg>  
10 Ideal     J     <tibble [896 × 8]>   <gg>  
# … with 25 more rows
```

I would like to print out each plot using `facet_wrap()` so they all appear together in a single chart. But I cannot even print them out one by one yet. Tried:

```
mydiamonds %>% map(plots, ~print(.x))
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'plots' not found
```

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do from that snippet - just print out each plot (This is within a Rmd code chunk so will print out nicely)

Bonus - assuming I figure out how to just print them out, is it possible to get them onto a single chart using `facet_wrap()` where the title would be paste0(cut, "|", color)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plots` column is not visible outside the data

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mydiamonds %>%
   ungroup %>%
   # either pull the column
   # or use `.$plots`
   pull(plots) %>%
   map(print)
```

Or use `walk`

```
mydiamonds %>%
   ungroup %>%
   pull(plots) %>%
   walk(print)
```

---

We could use `ggarrange` to get all the plot into a single page, but it would be too small

```
library(ggpubr)
mydiamonds %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pull(plots) %>%
    ggarrange(plotlist = ., nrow = 5, ncol = 7)
```

Or it may be better to export to `pdf`

```
mydiamonds %>%
    ungroup %>%
    pull(plots) %>%
    ggarrange(plotlist = ., nrow = 1, ncol = 1) %>%
    ggexport(., filename="plots.pdf")
```

check the output pdf

[image]

Comment: Why do we have to ungroup here?

Comment: @DougFir There is no need here, but I consider the group attributes unnecessary when we are looping over each element

Comment: If I can take a mile, would it be difficult to throw them all into a single chart using `facet_wrap()`?

Comment: @DougFir you have 35 plots, so the `ggarrange` (updated with `ggarrange`) would make each single plot extremely small.  (or even facet_wrap)

Comment: Thanks for this! My real data will have only 8 charts, for interest if we added a line after ungroup `%>% head %>%` to return only 5 or 6 rows, how would one use facet_wrap? I tried with `mydiamonds %>%
  ungroup %>%
  head %>% 
  pull(plots) %>%
  facet_wrap(vars('plots'))` which gave error

Comment: @DougFir it is separate plots that you generated.  `facet_wrap` should be used from a single data plot. you may need `pull(plots) %>%  ggarrange(plotlist = ., nrow = 3, ncol = 2)`